# Can we Insert rows while adding column to table In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a live running system. 
And we need to add a column to couple of tables while system is still running and processing/inserting data into those tables.The column which we need to to add is a non-mandatory column and database is Oracle.

Will this work fine or I need to stop the insertions before adding a column?

Comment: Adding a column to a large table can take a fair amount of time.

Comment: Will my inserts fail or just take longer i.e the inserts will wait for DDL to complete?

Comment: You could try this on a non-production system and see what happens. I imagine it will block but not sure. You could also explore editioning; not sure if it handles this sort of thing though.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Do you need to populate the new column for existing rows? If yes, with a default value or with bespoke values?

Comment: No it's optional column and I dont need to populate it for existing records or ones being inserted while creation of column